# how to create dynamic radio buttons in mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a complex need to create dynamic radio buttons.

The theory is you have categories and these categories have items.
The categories are dynamic and so are their items.

In my model i have...

public IList> ItemCategories { get; set; }

but I'm not sure if this is the correct way how to create the radioFor button?

help?

My initial Idea was...

//Model

```
public IList<Category> DynamicCategories { get; set; }

public IList<long> DynamicCategoryItems { get; set; }
```

//HTML

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.DynamicCategories.Count; i++)
{
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DynamicCategories[i], "DynamicCategories", new { Index = i, IsHidden = false })
}
```

//Editor

```
@model Category
@{
    Entities.Category rowModel = new Entities.Category();
    int count = ViewBag.Index == null ? 0 : (int)ViewBag.Index;
}

<h3>@Model.Name</h3>
<div class="options">
    @foreach (CategoryItem item in Model.CategoryItems.Where(x => x.Enabled))
    {
        <div class="option" data-search-text="@item.Name">
            @item.Name 
            <input type="radio" name="DynamicCategoryItems[@count]" value="@item.Id" @(item.Selected ? "checked" : "")/>
        </div>            
    }
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.DynamicCategories.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.DynamicCategories[i],model => model.DynamicCategoryItems[i]) @:Text

}
```

here Text is text for radiobutton.

Comment: Hi, if the radio button is inside a table and added dynamically, how to ensure its submitted on the Form POST. I followed your sample, which works. But, if I clone a row and add to the table, and generate the id it fails to POST false or true for the dynamically added vals

Comment: @transformer : Sorry for late reply, the reason behind it is when you add a new control its indexes should be in sequence. For example : `model.DynamicCategories[0], model.DynamicCategories[1]` , etc

When you'll correct the sequence, you'll start getting the responses.

Comment: Love your avatar! BTW can you show me how do it in the dynamically added/appended rows