# How to use dynamically Radiobutton in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, radio-button

I am creating a Poll in my ASP.NET MVC project.

1) I select poll and it's replies as an object of `Poll` model from database [poll model contain a list of reply model that named `PollReplies`]:

Poll model:

```
public class Poll
{
    public Poll() {
        PollReplies = new List<PollReply>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime SDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EDate { get; set; }
    public string User_ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Language_ID { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
    public bool ResultIsPublic { get; set; }
    public List<PollReply> PollReplies { get; set; }
}
```

Reply model:

```
public class PollReply
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Poll_ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

2) I render poll title of the selected poll object as question of poll.

3) With a `for` render replies:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.PollReplies.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PollReplies[i].ID, new { @Value = Model.PollReplies[i].ID })
    counter++;
    <tr>
        <td>@counter</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.PollReplies[i].Title)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.PollReplies[i].IsChecked,counter)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

My problem:

1) When I submit form, The `Poll` model is contain all replies. All replies has `ID` but the `IsChecked` propery of replies not set with the client selected radiobutton!(all `IsChecked` of replies are false) How I can post the selected reply as true?

2) I am using `@Html.RadioButtonFor` and radios give name attributes automaticly, so the name attribute of generated inputs are diffrente, but i need to just select one of radios! What is the best solution?

Comment: 1. for ischecked  issue use another feild as checkedid to store the replied id
2. use group/name

Comment: Can you explain more for problem 1? 
For problem 2 , I use `group` as an attribute but it does not work!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create dynamic radio buttons in mvc razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743718/how-to-create-dynamic-radio-buttons-in-mvc-razor)