# How to Bind Dynamically Generated Radio Buttons using RadioButtonFor to MVC Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating radio buttons in a razor file from a list which is populated from a database. As the list iterates it creates questions and radio option answers. The radio button option names are unique and generated on the fly. The syntax looks like this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.QuestionList[i].Question, Model.QuestionList[i].MarketingAnswerID)
@Html.Raw(Model.QuestionList[i].Answer)

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.QuestionList[i].Question, "", new { @class = "submission__required__field" })
```

I need a way to get the radio buttons binded to the model so I can make them required. My validation isn't working because the model I believe is what actually enforces the validation. How can I go about binding these radio options to the model considering the names are generated on the fly and the list may change.

Comment: Your radio button(s) are not making sense. You have not shown you models, but assuming you have a `Question` containing a collection of possible `Answer`, then you need to property (say) `SelectAnswer` to bind the radio buttons to.

Comment: We took a different path on this to meet time constraints. The radios did need to be fixed up and we created a model property for each one. No longer dynamic. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create dynamic radio buttons in mvc razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743718/how-to-create-dynamic-radio-buttons-in-mvc-razor)